# SqlLocalDB.msi and DBNETLIB / PowerShell SqlServer ServerConnections

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I'm trying to setup a development SQL server using SqlLocalDB.msi which installs a local version of SQL Server 2017.

I can connect to the SQL engine with SSMS (v14.0.17277.0) using MDAC (v10.17134.1).

But, when I open SQL Server Configuration Manager and click on SQL Server Network Configuration (32-bit), it says "There are no items to show in this view."

This appears to be a real problem because when a third-party app I have to use tries to open a connection to the database, it fails withthe following message:

[image: SQLError]

But, the Server *does* exist.  Here's a screen shot from SSMS:

[image: SSMS Screenshot]

Another clue to what may be going on is that no ServerInstances are listed when when I open an administrator Power Shell and do the following:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> import-module "sqlserver"
PS C:\Windows\system32> $smo = 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.'
>> $wmi = new-object ($smo + 'Wmi.ManagedComputer').
>>
>> # List the object properties, including the instance names.
>> $Wmi


ConnectionSettings : Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Wmi.WmiConnectionInfo
Services           : {}
ClientProtocols    : {np, sm, tcp}
ServerInstances    : {}
ServerAliases      : {}
Urn                : ManagedComputer[@Name='WINDEV1806EVAL']
Name               : WINDEV1806EVAL
Properties         : {}
UserData           :
State              : Existing
```

Does anyone know how to get SQL Server Express to work with DBNETLIB?

Comment: You should also use the latest [15.x SSMS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms?view=sql-server-ver15).

Answer (score 1):

SQL Express LocalDb is not going to work with the old ODBC driver that comes with Windows.  Either download and use a [newer ODBC driver](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=56567), or install the service-based [SQL Server Express Edition](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/sql-server-editions-express).

Comment: @david-browne-microsoft, thanks for the info.  I downloaded and installed the newer ODBC driver.  I'm not sure what the difference is between that and the SQL Server Express Edition.  After installing, the newer driver, I don't see any changes in the PowerShell output, or the SQL connect.  What would you do to verify the install?

Comment: You would have to reconfigure the app to use the other ODBC driver.  It may be as easy as updating a ODBC DSN, or there may be no way to do that.  Using the service-based SQL Server Express instead of LocalDB is more likely to succeed.